# Laravel using avg() function with foreign key

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I want to get the average rates for each product.

I have a **rates** table which has a foreign key to **product** table,
the **rates** table is similar to this

[image: a busy cat]

when I try to get products with this code:

```
$stocks = Stocks::with('images:url,color', 'tags:tag', 'sizes', 'rates')
                ->get()
                ->pluckDistant('tags', 'tag')
                ->pluckDistant('sizes', 'size');
```

it returns this

```
[
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "name",
        "image": "1564964985mI7jTuQEZxD49SGTce6Qntl7U8QDnc8uhVxedyYN.jpeg",
        "images": [
            {
                "url": "1564964985mI7jTuQEZxD49SGTce6Qntl7U8QDnc8uhVxedyYN.jpeg",
                "color": ""
            },
            {
                "url": "1564964985EV20c1jGvCVCzpCv2Gy9r5TnWM0hMpCBsiRbe8pI.png",
                "color": ""
            },
            {
                "url": "1564964985iFcMox6rjsUaM8CHil5oQ9HkrsDqTrqLNY1cXCRX.png",
                "color": ""
            }
        ],
        "tags": [
            "عطور"
        ],
        "sizes": [],
        "rates": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "stocks_id": 10,
                "rate": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "stocks_id": 10,
                "rate": 4
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

**How can I get the average of rates as  `"rates":3` using the eloquent relations to get them all by sql without php proccessing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could leverage something like [Appending](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json). Say you have a `Product` model which has a `OneToMany` relationship with `Rate` model.

Your `Product` model would look something like this:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['rates'];


    protected $appends = ['average_rate'];


    public function getAverageRateAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['average_rate'] = $this->rates->avg('rate');
    }

    public function rates() {
        return $this->hasMany(Rate::class);
    }
}
```

Now anytime you query your products from the database, you'll have the rate appended with the result.

```
array:7 [▼
  "id" => 1
  "created_at" => "2019-08-12 14:08:09"
  "updated_at" => "2019-08-12 14:08:09"
  "average_rate" => 4.5
  "rates" => array:2 [▶]
]
```

However, be aware of causing n+1 problem. If you're using this approach make sure to always eager load your `rates`.

Comment: Perfect! that works thanks a lot but how can I remove the `"rates"` array?
is there any way to do it without using $visible?

Comment: @WailHayaly Hmmm, I'm not really sure about this but take a look at [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources) if you want to be  explicit about how your final json result should look like. I hope that helped.

Comment: You're not appending a table, you're just adding an "extra" attribute to the returned result. So specifying a return type could do the trick. `return (int) $this->attributes['average_rate'] = $this->rates->avg('rate');`

Comment: Good answer!  I upvoted as it taught me a new feature.  However the average is being calculated in PHP on a `Collection` (from the eager-loaded `rates` relationship) and not performed in the SQL as per the question.

Comment: @erich that's correct, I think I forgot all about that note!

Comment: @AhmadH. i learned something else today: add the parentheses after `rate` in your attribute function.  `rate()` returns a query builder instead of a collection, and the aggregation will happen in SQL instead. `return $this->attributes['average_rate'] = $this->rates()->avg('rate');`
 ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852763/eloquent-orm-aggregation-vs-mysql-aggregation#comment93717802_40922629))

Comment: @erich Yes it will happen in SQL, but that is not recommended in this specific case, it will cause `n+1` problem. Say you query all products with `Product::all()->toArray()`, now with every single product your application will run a `select` query to get the `average_rate`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use join and use aggregate function on rates table.

```
Stocks::with('images:url,color', 'tags:tag', 'sizes')
 ->join('rates', 'rates.stocks_id', '=', 'stocks.id')
 ->selectRaw('stocks.*')
 ->selectRaw('AVG(rates.rate) as average_rating')
 ->selectRaw('tags.*')
 ->selectRaw('sizes.*')
 ->selectRaw('images.*')
 ->groupBy('stocks.id')
 ->get()
```

Comment: `"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in on clause is ambiguous (SQL: select AVG(stocks_rates.rate) from `stocks` inner join `stocks_rates` on `stocks_rates`.`stocks_id` = `id` group by `id`)"`

Comment: Sorry, replace `id` with `stocks.id`

Comment: `[
    {
        "AVG(stocks_rates.rate)": "3.0000",
        "images": [],
        "tags": [],
        "sizes": []
    }
]`

Comment: So everything is working great, the only thing left is to specify the other columns you want to select in the select statement. For example:

`Stocks::with('images:url,color', 'tags:tag', 'sizes')
 ->join('rates', 'rates.stocks_id', '=', 'id')
 ->selectRaw('AVG(rates.rate) as average_rating')
->selectRaw('tags.*')
->selectRaw('sizes.*')
->selectRaw('images.*)
 ->groupBy('id')
 ->get()`

Comment: I will just adjust my answer for redability

Comment: same result no changes

Comment: I think that we were missing the `selectRaw('stocks.*)` as the relationship couldnt find proper field to load them.